# Declaring a random amount of objects in c++

Tags: c++

So I have a decent amount of experience in other languages, but I am very new to c++.  I am trying to create a simple text based rpg where all there is is the player and a random number of enemies.  So the problem is when I try to move around in it I never run into an enemy, so I'm either having a problem creating the actual enemy objects, or my code for checking if the player is at the same location as an enemy isn't working, or maybe it's something else.  I'd really appreciate, some help.  Thanks.

Btw sorry my formatting got kind of messed up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define UP 1
#define RIGHT

class Character
{
public:
    int health, armour, speed, x, y, attackPower;
    Character()
    {
        health = 100;
        armour = 100;
        speed = 1;
    }

    bool isTouching(Character character)
    {
        if (x == character.x && y == character.y)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    void move(string dir)
    {
        if (dir == "up")
        {
            y += speed;
        }
        else if (dir == "down")
        {
            y -= speed;
        }
        else if (dir == "right")
        {
            x += speed;
        }
        else if (dir == "left")
        {
            x -= speed;
        }
    }

    void takeDamage(int damage)
    {
        if (armour > damage)
        {
            armour -= damage;
        }
        else
        {
            if (armour > 0)
            {
                int remainingDamage = damage - armour;
                armour = 0;
                health -= remainingDamage;
            }
        }
        health -= damage;
    }

    void attack(Character* character)
    {
        character->takeDamage(attackPower);
    }

};

class Player: public Character
{
public:
    Player()
    {
        health = 100;
        armour = 100;
        speed = 1;
        x = 10;
        y = 10;
        attackPower = 50;

    }
};


class Enemy : public Character
{
public:
    Enemy()
    {
        health = 100;
        armour = 0;
        speed = 1;
        x = rand() % 100;
        y = rand() % 100;
        attackPower = 20;

    }
};

int main()
{

    Character player;


    Enemy *enemies;
    int numEnemies = rand() % 30 + 20;
    enemies = new Enemy[numEnemies];

    while (true)
    {
        string input;
        cout << "Enter command: ";
        cin >> input;
        if (input == "exit" || input == "quit")
        {
            break;
        }
        if (input == "move")
        {
            string direction;
            cout << "pick a direction: ";
            cin >> direction;
            player.move(direction);

            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(enemies) / sizeof(int); i++)
            {
                if (player.isTouching(enemies[i]))
                {
                    cout << "You ran into an enemy!" << endl;
                    cout << "What would you like to do?: ";
                    string interactionInput;
                    cin >> interactionInput;
                    if (interactionInput == "attack")
                    {
                        player.attack(&enemies[i]);
                        enemies[i].attack(&player);
                        cout << "Enemy now at " << enemies[i].armour << " armour and " << enemies[i].health << " health" << endl;
                        cout << "You are now at " << player.armour << " armour and " << player.health << " health" << endl;
                    }
                }
            }

        }



    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector` for a dynamic array, not a raw pointer (which you leak).

Comment: Did you try debugging your program? What was the result of that effort ?

Comment: Adding to @chris comment:  `std::vector<Enemy>` or `std::vector<Enemy *>` or `std::vector< unique_ptr<Enemy> >`.

Comment: You should invest in a `Location` class and not have `x, y` in the character.  This helps later if the type of location changes (such as adding a height or country).  You could overload operator + for handling speed or changing position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(enemies)` is equal 4 or 8, depending on the size of your virtual memory address space.

`sizeof(int)` is equal 2 or 4, depending on your compiler definition (based on the underlying HW).

So `sizeof(enemies) / sizeof(int)` is somewhere between 1 and 4.

Having said that, you can simply use `numEnemies` instead.

---

If you allocated the `enemies` array statically (`Enemy enemies[...]`), then you could use:

```
sizeof(enemies)/sizeof(Enemy)
sizeof(enemies)/sizeof(*enemies)
sizeof(enemies)/sizeof(enemies[0]) // or any other index
```

But since you are allocating it dynamically, it is treated as a pointer (with a size of 4 or 8 bytes).

Comment: +1. This is because `sizeof(enemies)` means the size of the actual variable `enemies`, which in this case is a simple pointer, not an array.

Comment: @Cameron: Thanks. Perhaps I should indeed mention that it's because it's a pointer we're dealing with (although the "memory address space" part kind of implies it pretty well).

Comment: @monster3: You're welcome. I added a short explanation of when and how you may use `sizeof` in order to determine the size of an array. Please feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problem mentioned in the answer by barak manos, this line is probably an oversight.

```
Character player;
```

I think you meant to use:

```
Player player;
```

If you use the first line, the `x` and `y` values are not initialized. You'll get unpredictable behavior.