# Declaring a random amount of objects in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm basically trying to do what this guy is trying to do, but with Swift:

[Declaring a random amount of objects in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461210/declaring-a-random-amount-of-objects-in-c)

I'm pretty new to programming and very new to Swift so I'm a little fuzzy on how to do some things. Basically, I just want to declare a random amount of enemies that my player has to weave through and to register when he's hit one of them. I've been looking every where for an answer and either this is a really stupid question, so stupid no one has ever needed to put it on the internet, or Sift is too new for it to have been a problem for someone else. I'm guessing it's a stupid question, but regardless I'm out of ideas on how to figure this out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Swift arrays are dynamic, at least the mutable type that are declared with `var array`.
So you can just add objects to your array until you have enough objects.

e.g.:

```
var objects = [String]()

//let numberOfObjects = arc4random_uniform(10) // between 0 and 9
let numberOfObjects = arc4random_uniform(5) + 5 // between 5 and 9
for i in 0..<numberOfObjects {
    let object = String()
    objects.append(object)
}


println("we have \(countElements(objects)) objects")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm too dense to understand the question, but it seems to me that simply declaring an NSMutableArray would do what you want:

```
let myArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

You would have all the flexibility to add or remove objects as you please.

In any given loop, you could remove all objects, then use a random number generator to add back a random number of objects if that's what you're trying to do.

My additional comment on the other answer to this is that I would explicitly type cast everything in the statement that generates the random number:

```
var randomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using a simple Enemy class:

```
class Enemy : NSObject {
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

let range = (5, 20)
let numEnemies = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range.1 - range.0) + 1) + UInt32(range.0))
var enemyArray = [Enemy]()

for i in 0..<numEnemies {
    enemyArray.append(Enemy())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a random number of objects in an array.  Assume:

```
class MyObject {}
```

and that you have an upper bound on the number of objects:

```
let theObjectLimit = 10
```

then you can create a random number of new, distinct instances of `MyObject` with simply:

```
let theObjects = (1...arc4random_uniform(theObjectLimit)).map { 
   _ -> MyObject in return MyObject () 
}
```

When learning a language like Swift, that has first class functions (aka closures), you'll want to use functions like `map` and `reduce` wherever possible - especially instead of iteration.